# Efficient way to compute intersecting values between two numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a bottleneck in my program which is caused by the following:

```
A = numpy.array([10,4,6,7,1,5,3,4,24,1,1,9,10,10,18])
B = numpy.array([1,4,5,6,7,8,9])

C = numpy.array([i for i in A if i in B])
```

The expected outcome for `C` is the following:

```
C = [4 6 7 1 5 4 1 1 9]
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this operation?

Note that array `A` contains repeating values and they need to be taken into account. I wasn't able to use set intersection since taking the intersection will omit the repeating values, returning just `[1,4,5,6,7,9]`.

Also note this is only a simple demonstration. The actual array sizes can be in the order of thousands, to well over millions.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
>>> A[np.in1d(A, B)]
array([4, 6, 7, 1, 5, 4, 1, 1, 9])
```

`np.in1d` returns a boolean array indicating whether each value of `A` also appears in `B`. This array can then be used to index `A` and return the common values.

It's not relevant to your example, but it's also worth mentioning that if `A` and `B` each contain unique values then `np.in1d` can be sped up by setting `assume_unique=True`:

```
np.in1d(A, B, assume_unique=True)
```

You might also be interested in [`np.intersect1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) which returns an array of the unique values common to both arrays (sorted by value):

```
>>> np.intersect1d(A, B)
array([1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9])
```

Comment: So assuming that two arrays are unique, we could use either np.in1d and np.intersect1d. Could you comment on the performance between the two?

Comment: I've not tested performance of the two extensively, but `np.intersect1d` seems to be slightly quicker if `assume_unique` is set to `True` in both methods. I'm not sure of the exact reason why, but it may be because it has to do fewer comparisons.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`numpy.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
>>> A[np.in1d(A, B)]
array([4, 6, 7, 1, 5, 4, 1, 1, 9])
```

Answer (score 7):

We can use [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) for performance boost, more so for the case when the lookup array has sorted unique values -

```
def intersect1d_searchsorted(A,B,assume_unique=False):
    if assume_unique==0:
        B_ar = np.unique(B)
    else:
        B_ar = B
    idx = np.searchsorted(B_ar,A)
    idx[idx==len(B_ar)] = 0
    return A[B_ar[idx] == A]
```

That `assume_unique` flag makes it work for both generic case and the special case of `B` being unique and sorted.

Sample run -

```
In [89]: A = np.array([10,4,6,7,1,5,3,4,24,1,1,9,10,10,18])
    ...: B = np.array([1,4,5,6,7,8,9])

In [90]: intersect1d_searchsorted(A,B,assume_unique=True)
Out[90]: array([4, 6, 7, 1, 5, 4, 1, 1, 9])
```

Timings to compare against another vectorized `np.in1d` based solution (listed in two other answers) on large arrays for both cases -

```
In [103]: A = np.random.randint(0,10000,(1000000))

In [104]: B = np.random.randint(0,10000,(1000000))

In [105]: %timeit A[np.in1d(A, B)]
     ...: %timeit A[np.in1d(A, B, assume_unique=False)]
     ...: %timeit intersect1d_searchsorted(A,B,assume_unique=False)
1 loop, best of 3: 197 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 190 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 151 ms per loop

In [106]: B = np.unique(np.random.randint(0,10000,(5000)))

In [107]: %timeit A[np.in1d(A, B)]
     ...: %timeit A[np.in1d(A, B, assume_unique=True)]
     ...: %timeit intersect1d_searchsorted(A,B,assume_unique=True)
10 loops, best of 3: 130 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 218 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 80.2 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 4):

1-use the set intersection as it's super fast in this case

```
c = set(a).intersection(b)
```

2-use the numpy intersect1d method which is faster than looping but slower than the first method

```
c = numpy.intersect1d(a,b)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you check only for existence in `B` (`if i in B`) then obviously you **can** use a `set` for this. It doesn't matter how many fours there are in `B` as long as there is at least one. Of course you are right, that you can't use two sets and an intersection. But even one `set` should improve performance, as searching complexity is less than O(n):

```
A = numpy.array([10,4,6,7,1,5,3,4,24,1,1,9,10,10,18])
B = set([1,4,5,6,7,8,9])

C = numpy.array([i for i in A if i in B])
```