# Fastest way to find all indexes of matching values between two 1D arrays (with duplicates)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, performance

**Question description**

Lets say we have two simple arrays:

```
query = np.array([100, 4000, 500, 700, 400, 100])
match = np.array([6, 100, 4000, 100, 10, 8, 10])
```

I want to find the indexes of **all** matching values between the query and match. So in this case the result would be:

```
value   query   match
100        0    1
100        0    3
100        5    1
100        5    3
4000       1    2
```

In reality these arrays will contain millions of items

---

**"Stupid" loop solution**

```
qs = []
query_locs = []
match_locs = []

for i in np.arange(query.size):
    q = query[i]
    # Get matching indexes in "match"
    match_loc = np.where(match == q)[0]
    n = match_loc.size
    # Update location arrays
    match_locs.extend(match_loc)
    query_locs.extend(np.repeat(i,n))
    # Store the matching value
    qs.extend(np.repeat(q,n))

result = np.vstack((qs, query_locs, match_locs)).T
print(result)
 [[ 100    0    1]
 [ 100    0    3]
 [4000    1    2]
 [ 100    5    1]
 [ 100    5    3]]
```

(Maybe [`numba`](https://numba.pydata.org/) could make this loop pretty fast however when I tried this I got some errors about the signatures, so not sure about that)

---

**Numpy buildins**

There are quite some buildin numpy function to solve this problem for unique values, like using [`searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html), [`intersect1d`](http://numpy.intersect1d), however, as also described in the doc, they "Return the sorted, unique values" and thus do not take duplicates into account. Some examples on StackOverflow for this problem with unique values:

- [NumPy: Comparing Elements in Two Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613249/numpy-comparing-elements-in-two-arrays)
- [Efficient way to compute intersecting values between two numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27967914/efficient-way-to-compute-intersecting-values-between-two-numpy-arrays)

I could imagine there would be a *faster* way to do this with numpy instead of a loop, so curious to see an answer!

Answer (score 3):

You may transform 1d-arrays to dataframes and make a join, like this:

```
query = np.array([100, 4000, 500, 700, 400, 100])
match = np.array([6, 100, 4000, 100, 10, 8, 10])
dfquery = pd.DataFrame(range(len(query)), index=query, columns=['query'])
dfmatch = pd.DataFrame(range(len(match)), index=match, columns=['match'])
dfquery.join(dfmatch, how='inner')
```

Result:

```
    query   match
100     0       1
100     0       3
100     5       1
100     5       3
4000    1       2
```

Comment: This gave me some good ideas, and it's fast too, thanks! Even faster when using `set_index()` and `sort_index()`

Answer (score 0):

You could hack around it with newaxis:

```py
>>> comparison = np.equal(query[:, np.newaxis], match[np.newaxis, :])
array([[False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False]])
```

which essentially creates the cartesian product (`query` x `matches`) (note the memory cost) and then applies the binary function `np.equal` to cast each element in the product space to a `bool` efficiently.
The output can be interpreted by reading it row-wise as: query element i is equal to match element j whenever `comparison[i, j]` is `True`.
You can gather the indices of all `True` pairs with:

```py
list(zip(*comparison.nonzero()))
[(0, 1), (0, 3), (1, 2), (5, 1), (5, 3)]
```

ps: If the arrays are too long to construct the product, iterating over them element-wise is your only option.

Comment: With millions of items this for sure won't be achievable with classical hardware.

Comment: Sure, it scales badly in terms of memory costs, but it's the fastest way to go about it if your array sizes are manageable.

Comment: I just said it because OP mentioned "*In reality these arrays will contain millions of items*", I love numpy broadcasting, but clearly not applicable here ;)

Comment: ohh, I actually missed that line