# The most efficient way rather than using np.setdiff1d and np.in1d, to remove common values of 1D arrays with unique values

Tags: python, numpy, performance, optimization, numba

I need a much faster code to remove values of an 1D array (array length ~ 10-15) that are common with another 1D array (array length ~ 1e5-5e5 --> *rarely* up to 7e5), which are index arrays contain integers. There is no duplicate in the arrays, and they are not sorted and the order of the values must be kept in the main array after modification. I know that can be achieved using such `np.setdiff1d` or `np.in1d` (*which both are not supported for numba jitted in no-python mode*), and other similar posts (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27967914/13394817)) have not much more efficient way to do so, but performance is important here because all the values in the main index array will be gradually be removed in loops.

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

n = 500000
r = 10
arr1 = np.random.permutation(n)
arr2 = np.random.randint(0, n, r)

# @nb.jit
def setdif1d_np(a, b):
    return np.setdiff1d(a, b, assume_unique=True)


# @nb.jit
def setdif1d_in1d_np(a, b):
    return a[~np.in1d(a, b)]
```

There is another related post that proposed by [*norok2*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66674679/13394817) for 2D arrays, that is ~15 times faster solution (hashing-like way using numba) than usual methods described there. This solution may be the best if it could be prepared for 1D arrays:

```
@nb.njit
def mul_xor_hash(arr, init=65537, k=37):
    result = init
    for x in arr.view(np.uint64):
        result = (result * k) ^ x
    return result


@nb.njit
def setdiff2d_nb(arr1, arr2):
    # : build `delta` set using hashes
    delta = {mul_xor_hash(arr2[0])}
    for i in range(1, arr2.shape[0]):
        delta.add(mul_xor_hash(arr2[i]))
    # : compute the size of the result
    n = 0
    for i in range(arr1.shape[0]):
        if mul_xor_hash(arr1[i]) not in delta:
            n += 1
    # : build the result
    result = np.empty((n, arr1.shape[-1]), dtype=arr1.dtype)
    j = 0
    for i in range(arr1.shape[0]):
        if mul_xor_hash(arr1[i]) not in delta:
            result[j] = arr1[i]
            j += 1
    return result
```

I tried to prepare that for 1D arrays, but I have some problems/question with that.

- At first, IDU what does `mul_xor_hash` exactly do, and if `init` and `k` are arbitrary selected or not
- Why `mul_xor_hash` will not work without `nb.njit`:

```
  File "C:/Users/Ali/Desktop/test - Copy - Copy.py", line 21, in mul_xor_hash
    result = (result * k) ^ x
TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_xor' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

- IDK how to implement `mul_xor_hash` on 1D arrays (if it could), which I guess may make it faster more than for 2Ds, so I broadcast the input arrays to 2D by `[None, :]`, which get the following error just for `arr2`:

```
    print(mul_xor_hash(arr2[0]))
ValueError: new type not compatible with array
```

- and what does `delta` do

I am searching the most efficient way in this regard. In the absence of better method than *norok2 solution*, how to prepare this solution for 1D arrays?

Comment: The `numpy` code of `setdiff1d` just does what your 2nd version does - using `in1d`.  Read it for yourself.  `in1d` with one array much smaller, does a `mask |= (arr1 == a)` for each element of the `arr2`.  there's nothing super fancy about this.  For a big size difference this is considered to be faster than sorting.  It's easy to read the `in1d` code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Understanding the hash-based solution

> At first, IDU what does mul_xor_hash exactly do, and if init and k are arbitrary selected or not

`mul_xor_hash` is a custom hash function. Functions mixing xor and multiply (possibly with shifts) are known to be relatively fast to compute the hash of a raw data buffer. The multiplication tends to shuffle bits and the xor is used to somehow combine/accumulate the result in a fixed size small value (ie. the final hash). There are many different hashing functions. Some are faster than others, some cause more collisions than other in a given context. A fast hashing function causing too many collisions can be useless in practice as it would result in a pathological situation where all conflicting values needs to be compared. This is why fast hash functions are hard to implement.

`init` and `k` are parameter certainly causing the hash to be pretty balance. This is pretty common in such a hash function. `k` needs to be sufficiently big for the multiplication to shuffle bits and it should typically also be a prime number (values like power of two tends to increase collisions due to modular arithmetic behaviours). `init` plays a significant role only for very small arrays (eg. with 1 item): it helps to reduce collisions by xoring the final hash by a non-trivial constant. Indeed, if `arr.size = 1`, then `result = (init * k) ^ arr[0]` where `init * k` is a constant. Having an identity hash function equal to `arr[0]` is known to be bad since it tends to result in many collisions (this is a complex topic, but put it shortly, `arr[0]` can be divided by the number of buckets in the hash table for example). Thus, `init` should be a relatively big number and `init * k` should also be a big non-trivial value (a prime number is a good target value).

> Why mul_xor_hash will not work without nb.njit

It depends of the input. The input needs to be a 1D array and have a raw size in byte divisible by 8 (eg. 64-bit items, 2n x 32-bit ones, 4n x 16-bit one or 8n 8-bit ones). Here is some examples:

```py
mul_xor_hash(np.random.rand(10))
mul_xor_hash(np.arange(10)) # Do not work with 9
```

> and what does delta do

It is a `set` containing the hash of the `arr2` row so to find matching lines faster than comparing them without hashes.

> how to prepare this solution for 1D arrays?

AFAIK, hashes are only use to avoid comparisons of rows but this is because the input is the 2D array. In 1D, there is no such a problem.

There is big catch with this method: it only works if there is no hash collisions. Otherwise, the implementation wrongly assumes that values are equal even if they are not! @norok explicitly mentioned it in the comments though:

> Note that the collision handling for the hashings should also be implemented

---

### Faster implementation

Using the 2D solution of @norok2 for 1D is not a good idea since hashes will not make it faster the way they are used. In fact, a `set` already use a hash function internally anyway. Not to mention collisions needs to be properly implemented (which is done by a `set`).

Using a `set` is a relatively good idea since it causes the complexity to be `O(n + m)` where `n = len(arr1)` and `m = len(arr2)`. That being said, if `arr1` is converted to a `set`, then it will be too big to fit in L1 cache (due to the size of `arr1` in your case) resulting in slow cache misses. Additionally, the growing size of the `set` will cause values to be re-hashed which is not efficient. If `arr2` is converted to a `set`, then the many hash table fetches will not be very efficient since `arr2` is very small in your case. This is why this solution is sub-optimal.

One solution is to **split `arr1` in chunks** and then build a `set` based on the target chunk. You can then check if a value is in the set or not efficiently. Building the set is still not very efficient due to the growing size. This problem is due to Python itself which do not provide a way to reserve some space for the data structure like other languages do (eg. C++). One solution to avoid this issue is simply to reimplement an hash-table which is not trivial and cumbersome. Actually, [**Bloom filters**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) can be used to speed up this process since they can quickly find if there is no collision between the two sets `arr1` and `arr2` in average (though they are not trivial to implement).

Another optimization is to use **multiple threads** to compute the chunks in parallel since they are independent. That being said, the appending to the final array is not easy to do efficiently in parallel, especially since you do not want the order to be modified. One solution is to move away the copy from the parallel loop and do it serially but this is slow and AFAIK there is no simple way to do that in Numba currently (since the parallelism layer is very limited). Consider using native languages like C/C++ for an efficient parallel implementation.

In the end, hashing can be pretty complex and the speed up can be quite small compared to a naive implementation with two nested loops since `arr2` only have few items and modern processors can compare values quickly using **SIMD instructions** (while hash-based method can hardly benefit from them on mainstream processors). Unrolling can help to write a pretty simple and fast implementation. Again, unfortunately, Numba use LLVM-Jit internally which appear to fail to vectorize such a simple code (certainly due to *missing optimizations* in either LLVM-Jit or even LLVM itself). As a result, the non vectorized code is finally a bit slower (rather than 4~10 times faster on a modern mainstream processor). One solution is to use a C/C++ code instead to do that (or possibly Cython).

Here is a serial implementation using basic Bloom filters:

```py
@nb.njit('uint32(int32)')
def hash_32bit_4k(value):
    return (np.uint32(value) * np.uint32(27_644_437)) & np.uint32(0x0FFF)

@nb.njit(['int32[:](int32[:], int32[:])', 'int32[:](int32[::1], int32[::1])'])
def setdiff1d_nb_faster(arr1, arr2):
    out = np.empty_like(arr1)
    bloomFilter = np.zeros(4096, dtype=np.uint8)
    for j in range(arr2.size):
        bloomFilter[hash_32bit_4k(arr2[j])] = True
    cur = 0
    for i in range(arr1.size):
        # If the bloom-filter value is true, we know arr1[i] is not in arr2.
        # Otherwise, there is maybe a false positive (conflict) and we need to check to be sure.
        if bloomFilter[hash_32bit_4k(arr1[i])] and arr1[i] in arr2:
            continue
        out[cur] = arr1[i]
        cur += 1
    return out[:cur]
```

Here is an untested variant that should work for 64-bit integers (floating point numbers need memory views and possibly a prime constant too):

```py
@nb.njit('uint64(int64)')
def hash_32bit_4k(value):
    return (np.uint64(value) * np.uint64(67_280_421_310_721)) & np.uint64(0x0FFF)
```

Note that if all the values in the small array are contained in the main array in each loop, then we can speed up the `arr1[i] in arr2` part by removing values from `arr2` when we find them. That being said, collisions and findings should be very rare so I do not expect this to be significantly faster (not to mention it adds some overhead and complexity). If items are computed in chunks, then the last chunks can be directly copied without any check but the benefit should still be relatively small. Note that this strategy can be effective for the naive (C/C++) SIMD implementation previously mentioned though (it can be about 2x faster).

---

### Generalization and parallel implementation

This section focus on the algorithm to use regarding the input size. It particularly details an SIMD-based implementation and discuss about the use of multiple threads.

First of all, regarding the value `r`, the best algorithm to use can be different. More specifically:

- when `r` is 0, the best thing to do is to return the input array `arr1` unmodified (possibly a copy to avoid issue with in-place algorithms);
- when `r` is 1, we can use one basic loop iterating over the array, but the best implementation is likely to use `np.where` of Numpy which is highly optimized for that
- when `r` is small like <10, then using a SIMD-based implementation should be particularly efficient, especially if the iteration range of the `arr2`-based loop is known at compile-time and is unrolled
- for bigger `r` values that are still relatively small (eg. `r < 1000` and `r << n`), the provided hash-based solution should be one of the best;
- for larger `r` values with `r << n`, the hash-based solution can be optimized by packing boolean values as bits in `bloomFilter` and by using multiple hash-functions instead of one so to better handle collisions while being more cache-friendly (in fact, this is what actual bloom filters does); note that multi-threading can be used so speed up the lookups when `r` is huge and `r << n`;
- when `r` is big and not much smaller than `n`, then the problem is pretty hard to solve efficiently and the best solution is certainly to sort both arrays (typically with a radix sort) and use a merge-based method to remove the duplicates, possibly with multiple threads when both `r` and `n` are huge (hard to implement).

Let's start with the SIMD-based solution. Here is an implementation:

```py
@nb.njit('int32[:](int32[::1], int32[::1])')
def setdiff1d_nb_simd(arr1, arr2):
    out = np.empty_like(arr1)
    limit = arr1.size // 4 * 4
    limit2 = arr2.size // 2 * 2
    cur = 0
    z32 = np.int32(0)

    # Tile (x4) based computation
    for i in range(0, limit, 4):
        f0, f1, f2, f3 = z32, z32, z32, z32
        v0, v1, v2, v3 = arr1[i], arr1[i+1], arr1[i+2], arr1[i+3]
        # Unrolled (x2) loop searching for a match in `arr2`
        for j in range(0, limit2, 2):
            val1 = arr2[j]
            val2 = arr2[j+1]
            f0 += (v0 == val1) + (v0 == val2)
            f1 += (v1 == val1) + (v1 == val2)
            f2 += (v2 == val1) + (v2 == val2)
            f3 += (v3 == val1) + (v3 == val2)
        # Remainder of the previous loop
        if limit2 != arr2.size:
            val = arr2[arr2.size-1]
            f0 += v0 == val
            f1 += v1 == val
            f2 += v2 == val
            f3 += v3 == val
        if f0 == 0: out[cur] = arr1[i+0]; cur += 1
        if f1 == 0: out[cur] = arr1[i+1]; cur += 1
        if f2 == 0: out[cur] = arr1[i+2]; cur += 1
        if f3 == 0: out[cur] = arr1[i+3]; cur += 1

    # Remainder
    for i in range(limit, arr1.size):
        if arr1[i] not in arr2:
            out[cur] = arr1[i]
            cur += 1

    return out[:cur]
```

It turns out this implementation is always slower than the hash-based one on my machine since Numba clearly generate an inefficient for the inner `arr2`-based loop and this appears to come from broken optimizations related to the `==`: Numba simply fail use SIMD instructions for this operation (for no apparent reasons). This prevent many alternative SIMD-related codes to be fast as long as they are using Numba.

Another issue with Numba is that `np.where` is slow since it use a naive implementation while the one of Numpy has been heavily optimized. The optimization done in Numpy can hardly be applied to the Numba implementation due to the previous issue. This prevent any speed up using `np.where` in a Numba code.

In practice, the hash-based implementation is pretty fast and the copy takes a significant time on my machine already. The computing part can be speed up using multiple thread. This is not easy since the parallelism model of Numba is very limited. The copy cannot be easily optimized with Numba (one can use non-temporal store but this is not yet supported by Numba) unless the computation is possibly done in-place.

To use multiple threads, one strategy is to first split the range in chunk and then:

- build a boolean array determining, for each item of `arr1`, whether the item is found in `arr2` or not (fully parallel)
- count the number of item found by chunk (fully parallel)
- compute the offset of the destination chunk (hard to parallelize, especially with Numba, but fast thanks to chunks)
- copy the chunk to the target location without copying found items (fully parallel)

Here is an efficient parallel hash-based implementation:

```py
@nb.njit('int32[:](int32[:], int32[:])', parallel=True)
def setdiff1d_nb_faster_par(arr1, arr2):
    # Pre-computation of the bloom-filter
    bloomFilter = np.zeros(4096, dtype=np.uint8)
    for j in range(arr2.size):
        bloomFilter[hash_32bit_4k(arr2[j])] = True

    chunkSize = 1024 # To tune regarding the kind of input
    chunkCount = (arr1.size + chunkSize - 1) // chunkSize

    # Find for each item of `arr1` if the value is in `arr2` (parallel)
    # and count the number of item found for each chunk on the fly.
    # Note: thanks to page fault, big parts of `found` are not even written in memory if `arr2` is small
    found = np.zeros(arr1.size, dtype=nb.bool_)
    foundCountByChunk = np.empty(chunkCount, dtype=nb.uint16)
    for i in nb.prange(chunkCount):
        start, end = i * chunkSize, min((i + 1) * chunkSize, arr1.size)
        foundCountInChunk = 0
        for j in range(start, end):
            val = arr1[j]
            if bloomFilter[hash_32bit_4k(val)] and val in arr2:
                found[j] = True
                foundCountInChunk += 1
        foundCountByChunk[i] = foundCountInChunk

    # Compute the location of the destination chunks (sequential)
    outChunkOffsets = np.empty(chunkCount, dtype=nb.uint32)
    foundCount = 0
    for i in range(chunkCount):
        outChunkOffsets[i] = i * chunkSize - foundCount
        foundCount += foundCountByChunk[i]

    # Parallel chunk-based copy
    out = np.empty(arr1.size-foundCount, dtype=arr1.dtype)
    for i in nb.prange(chunkCount):
        srcStart, srcEnd = i * chunkSize, min((i + 1) * chunkSize, arr1.size)
        cur = outChunkOffsets[i]
        # Optimization: we can copy the whole chunk if there is nothing found in it 
        if foundCountByChunk[i] == 0:
            out[cur:cur+(srcEnd-srcStart)] = arr1[srcStart:srcEnd]
        else:
            for j in range(srcStart, srcEnd):
                if not found[j]:
                    out[cur] = arr1[j]
                    cur += 1

    return out
```

This implementation is the fastest for the target input on my machine. It is generally fast when `n` is quite big and the overhead to create threads is relatively small on the target platform (eg. on PCs but typically not computing servers with many cores). The overhead of the parallel implementation is significant so the number of core on the target machine needs to be at least 4 so the implementation can be significantly faster than the sequential implementation.

It may be useful to tune the `chunkSize` variable for the target inputs. If `r << n`, it is better to use a pretty big chunkSize. That being said, the number of chunk needs to be sufficiently big for multiple thread to operate on many chunks. Thus, `chunkSize` should be significantly smaller than `n / numberOfThreads`.

On my machine most of the time (65-70%) is spent in the final copy which is mostly memory-bound and can hardly be optimized further with Numba.

---

### Results

Here are results on my i5-9600KF-based machine (with 6 cores):

```
setdif1d_np:               2.65 ms
setdif1d_in1d_np:          2.61 ms
setdiff1d_nb:              2.33 ms
setdiff1d_nb_simd:         1.85 ms
setdiff1d_nb_faster:       0.73 ms
setdiff1d_nb_faster_par:   0.49 ms
```

The best provided implementation is about 4~5 time faster than the other ones.

Comment: 4096 is quite carefully chosen. 1. It needs to match with the mask in the `hash_32bit_4k` function. 2. It needs to be a power of two (so the mask is can be equivalent to a fast modulus). 3. It needs to fit in the L1 cache and possibly in few memory pages. 4. It needs to be sufficiently big so to avoid collisions regarding the number of items in `arr2`. For example 8192 also works well when I tested it on my machine. The collisions are taken into account in the code so results should always be correct (at least with this input data type).

Comment: I edited the post to add information about 64-bit integers and about the inclusion of arr2 in arr1. I agree for the generalization. In fact, I am wondering if such a strategy could be directly implemented in `np.setdiff1d` (of the Numpy implementation, not Numba) though it might be a significant work.

Comment: So, 4096 don't need to be changed for 64bit (`setdiff1d_nb_faster` don't need any change just signature), too? and no need to remove values from `arr2` (negligible effect on performance)? It seems you consider two  different signature styles; Does it have a negative effect than using just one if we know their type e.g. `C` --> just `[::1]`? some benchmarks on colab: **just** for `r=1` the solution is a little slower (very near) than the numpy ones for 32bit arrays; But, for 64bit (my case), it is at least 1.5 times faster, even for small `r` values e.g. `1`.

Comment: 4096 can be left untouched yes. Sure the signature needs to be adapted to the input type for 64 bit ones. `::1` mean the axis is contiguous so access are generally faster with that, but you cannot provide non contiguous array to a Numba method accepting contiguous one (while the opposite is possible).

Comment: Results on Colab are generally not very stable or good for reproducibility (since AFAIK machines are shared with other users). Also results are dependent of the platform. The target processor may be able to saturate a core RAM bandwidth on such platform. If so, no code will be faster. It is hard to tell without a profiling. Note that you may need to tweak parameters.

Answer (score 4):

What I found is that hashing does not help,. It is just trick for 2D case, to convert 1d arrays to single numbers and put them as such in a set.

Below is method of norok2 I converted to 1d arrays (and added annotations for faster compilation).
Note that this is only slightly (20-30%) faster than the methods you already have. And of course after second function call, on first due to compilation it is slightly slower.

```
@nb.njit('int32[:](int32[:], int32[:])')
def setdiff1d_nb(arr1, arr2):
    delta = set(arr2)

    # : build the result
    result = np.empty(len(arr1), dtype=arr1.dtype)
    j = 0
    for i in range(arr1.shape[0]):
        if arr1[i] not in delta:
            result[j] = arr1[i]
            j += 1
    return result[:j]
```

Comment: I checked for some random values in the specified array sizes, your first solution was faster than this? is it? I used 64bit integers layout C.

Comment: @Ali_Sh I have not tested speed-up after editing. Did two modifications suggested by norok2 (he removed his comment). Hmmm, maybe last line `result[:j]` which was not present caused slow down

Comment: to clarify: norok2 suggestions where correct and had to take them into account. My original version did not take into account the fact that numbers in arr2 may repeat (rare in your case but still..)